# Add UIButton programmatically from a IBAction

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to make an action where every time you press a button, it adds a button to the view. Nothing I have tried works.

It would be much appreciated if someone could clear up what to do.

This is the most recent attempt at my button-adding button:

```
-(IBAction) addButton{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
    button.tag = 1;

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonTouched:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the method is called?

Comment: Check for IBAction wired up correctly. Sometimes in hurry we miss to bind actions/iboutlets...

Comment: Also make sure that `view` is not `nil`.

Comment: Above code is perfect but the button is transparent so is not visible. simple. change its background color or set an image. this will definitely work. and every time change the frame otherwise every buttons will overlap others.

Comment: there is a warning that says local declaration of 'button' hides instance variable... is that okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];

Try the above codes.
```

Comment: there is a warning that says local declaration of 'button' hides instance variable... is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this

```
   #import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>
```

then Do the follow this

```
 -(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender{
         NSLog(@"New Button Clicked");
     }
     -(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender
     {
         UIButton *btnallstates;
         UIImage *statesbtnimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
         btnallstates=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];
         btnallstates.tag=1;
         btnallstates.frame=CGRectMake(103, 127, 193, 31);
         [btnallstates.layer setBorderWidth:0];
         [btnallstates addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [btnallstates setBackgroundImage:statesbtnimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.view addSubview:btnallstates];

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Only change this line

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

to

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

to show the button on the view.

`UIButtonTypeCustom` does not show up although it is added to the view.

Your can understand this by changing the color of the button.
e.g change the code to this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Hope it works. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
 [self.view addSubview:button];
```